# Using IdentityServer 4 and ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, webforms, jwt, identityserver4

I have some legacy web form ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) which are working with my own custom implemented SSO application.

Now, I want to use IdentityServer 4 instead of my SSO application.

I have seen all the sample codes for IdentintyServer [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples), but there is no sample application for Web Form.

Just to mention that in my old web form application I didn't use Owin or any other middle-ware.

Is there any sample for that or I should refactor the codes for MVC samples to be used in Web Form?

Answer (score 1):

You can check what brockallen (one of the IdentityServer authors) says in [his](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/78#issuecomment-213808426) comment.

In my current solutions, were I have Web Forms client, I use `IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation` and `IdentityModel` libraries (`IdentityModel` should be v <2.0). There is no issue, connecting with these libraries to IdentityServer 4 and authenticating.

If you are forced to not use the Owin Middleware, you will have to end up with some custom implementation and calls to the IdentityServer endpoints etc. But if there is no stopper for you using it - this will be your preferred way.